# Exceeded maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, recursion

Hey I am writing a some code for a challenge where we have to find the number of encodings in a string of numbers where each number is mapped to its corresponding alphabet, eg. A=1....Z=26. So if we have 123 we would have 1 2 3, 12 3 , and 1 23 so 3 decodings. I wrote some code below which I am pretty sure should work but I am getting a maximum recursion depth error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def num_decodes(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 1
    elif len(s) == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        if int(s[0]) == 1:
            return num_decodes(s[0:]) + num_decodes(s[1:])
        elif int(s[0]) ==2 and int(s[1])<=6:
            return num_decodes(s[0:]) + num_decodes(s[1:])
        else:
            return num_decodes(s[0:])


print(num_decodes('321'))
```

Comment: `num_decodes(s[0:])` is the same thing as `num_decodes(s)`, so you are endlessly calling the same function.

Comment: You *think* you're shortening the array each recursive call to num_decoes() ... but you're not.  Instead, you've got an infinite recursion.  SUGGESTION: step through under the debugger: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html.  Then revisit the syntax for Python array slices: https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

Comment: And just out of curiosity.  What do you return if s[0] == '0'?  This code is also a really good candidate for @functools.lrucache(None).  Even once you fix your bug, you're going to be repeated calling multiple times with the same argument.  Imagine your input strings is "1111314159".  You'll be calling `num_decodes("314159")` 8 times.

Comment: Yep that worked. Thank you guys!

Comment: @FrankYellin how would I be calling it 8 times?

Comment: 1,1,1,1,...; 11,1,1,....; 1,11,1,....; 1,1,11,....; 11,11,......    Sorry, I miscounted, six.  You'll parse AAAA then call `num_decode("314159")`.  Then you'll parse "KAA" and call it again.  Then "AKA", "AAK", "KK".